# Splitting sentence doesn't work if I am trying to split the last word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to split a sentence by removing a certain word
for example:

```
var word = "am";
var sentence = "Hello am I John?";

var stringpart2 = sentence.split(" ");
var stringpart1 = stringpart2.splice(0,stringpart2.indexOf(word));
stringpart2.remove(word);
stringpart1.remove(word);

var istring1 = stringpart1.toString();
var finalpart1 = istring1.replace(/,/g, " ");
var istring2 = stringpart2.toString();
var finalpart2 = istring2.replace(/,/g, " ");
```

now this works as it returns this:

```
finalpart1 = "Hello I"
finalpart2 = "John?"
```

but when I make the word the last word in the sentence:

```
var word = "John";
```

it returns

```
finalpart1 = ""
finalpart2 = "Hello am I John?"
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this so its like this:

```
finalpart1 = "Hello am I?"
finalpart2 = ""
```

It might be worth mentioning I'm taking the word and the sentence out of an array that I get through $.getJSON and if the word is the first word of the sentence it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression:

```js
function replace(text, word) {
  return text.replace(new RegExp('\\s\\b' + word + '|' + word + '\\b\\s'), '')
}

const text = 'Hello am I John?'

console.log( replace(text, 'Hello') )
console.log( replace(text, 'am') )
console.log( replace(text, 'John') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split directly by the word:

```
var splitted = sentence.split(word);
console.log(splitted[0], splitted[1], etc...);
```

In this case if you split by John it will look exactly like you want.